# Does SourceTree actually support merge without commiting?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

There is the GIT command

```
"git merge --no-ff --no-commit {branchtobemerged}
```

In SourceTree I find no way to do it via the UI, I need to do it via the Terminal. I did try to uncheck the **"Commit merge immediately (if no conflicts)"** option of the merge but it still does the commit anyway.

This is troublesome if I need to review the differences and reject certain files i do not want merged together.

Any one found a way to get this to work?

Comment: Yes I face the same issue